# Как скрыть файл (или его содержание)

Tags: python

Нужно создать файл, чтобы одна программа написала туда рандомное число, а другая его смогла прочесть, но проблема в том, что бы этот файл не мог открыть и изменить юзер.

Comment: Он всегда его откроет и изменит, если захочет, независимо от расширения

Comment: Можешь даже вообще без расширения создавать, открыть его не проблема...а юзер его всегда сможет открыть и изменить, если очень захочет. Как защиту от дурака можно писать туда не в открытом виде, а бинарные данные или даже немного шифрованные. Но в отладчике всё равно кому надо, найдут как они шифруются )

Comment: кажется, кто то пытается изобрести named pipe или сокеты

Comment: Если одна записать, другая прочитать, то тут хорошо б сделать ключевую пару и шифровать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь 1 попробовать сделать свой файл скрытым.
На Windows делается как-то так

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["attrib","+H","myfile.txt"])
```

На Linux подобных ОС это можно просто добавить "." в начало файла.

Но в любом случае, что на Windows что на Linux пользователь сможет его редактировать или просматривать, если захочет.

Путь 2 использовать шифрование.
Пользователь увидит шированный текст, который представляет из себя какой-то мусор и абрукадабру

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

text = 'TOP SECRET TEXT'.rjust(32)                  #текст который мы хотим зашифровать
secret_key = 'qwerty'.rjust(32)                     # пароль

cipher = AES.new(secret_key,AES.MODE_ECB)         
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(text))    # зашифрованный текст
decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encoded)) # расшифорванный текст
```

Comment: Запускать внешнюю программу для установки атрибута файла - это за гранью добра и зла. Лучше тогда уж bat-файлы писать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ю̶н̶и̶к̶с̶в̶е̶й̶н̶о̶!̶

Comment: Пользователь попреки шифрованию **может изменить** содержание. Нужна автентизация.